# How to authenticate a WCF Rest?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, ssl

I have been learning WCf and have developed a WCF Rest application. But now i am looking at how secure my WCF methods. From what i have read in MSDN, it's says that for a REST application, the only way to secure is to use SSL certificate. I have read that there is a lot of ways to secure a WS-Service. I want to know if there are other methods to secure and authenticate REST service? My service will be used in an application, web application and in mobile app. My requirement is that if i call a WCF method and that call should expire within a specific time no matter if no result has returned.

Regards,
Rajagopalan